# Resteasy @POST annotated method not called

Tags: annotations, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using Resteasy 2.3.5. The following `@POST` annotated method is never called, when I request its URL `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest/echo/foobar` in my browser:

```
@POST
@Path("/echo/{msg}")
@Produces("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
public String echo(@PathParam("msg") final String msg) {
    return msg;
}
```

However, when I replace `@POST` by `@GET` it works just fine (the browser returns `foobar`). What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your browser will always do a GET request when you type a URL.
Try downloading a HTTP client tool like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/). Then run the following test from your command line environment:

`curl "http://localhost:8080/MyApp/rest/echo/foobar" -X POST`

You can play around with any of the HTTP methods, headers, etc. Give it a try.

Comment: Sometimes you just don't see the wood for the trees... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `@POST` annotation refers to the HTTP POST request method. Your web browser will normally only issue GET HTTP request methods, which is why your example works when you change to `@GET`. There are many tools you can use to help you test your REST service, some of them work form right inside your browser.

For Firefox try https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/

For Chrome try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en

You can also see
[What tools do you use to test your public REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486658/what-tools-do-you-use-to-test-your-public-rest-api)

Comment: Thanks for the Firefox plugin, will have a look at it.